# Change user and group of files at the time of upload?

Tags: php, file-upload

In my application, I have provided facility to upload images. But when someone uploads images then it uploaded to server with default permissions `600` and with user `www-data`. My FTP username is different its say `uvideo`.

As images are uploaded with default `www-data`, so when I am trying to change or delete them via FTP, then its not working.

I want them to be uploaded with username and group as `uvideo`? Is it possible in php?

Or if not then is there any possibility to achieve the same via server, I am using `Ubuntu` LAMP setup.

Please help, thanks!

Comment: Only `root` can change the owner and/or group of a file, so I'm not sure if there is a solution.

Comment: `chown()` change group `chmod()` change permissions

Answer (score 0):

PHP has a command [chown](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chown.php) but you can't use it unless your web server is running as root **which you should never do**

> Attempts to change the owner of the file filename to user user. Only the superuser may change the owner of a file.

There is also [chgrp](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chgrp.php) but you limited to changing the group to only groups the web user is able to.

You can however use [chmod](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php) to make the file writeable by your ftp user account.

You could also, add your ftp user to the same group as your web user and and set group write permissions `chmod 0775`